# PA-RISC inline assembly with HP CC compiler

Tags: c, assembly, hp-ux, pa-risc

I need to port some code written with a GCC compiler and inline assembly to its HP Unix equivalent. The situation is that HP CC compiler does not support the _asm keyword and of course the syntax is completely different. I have been looking on the internet for days but I have not found much information. The most I got is some information about the header file inline.h which has all the definitions of some macros that, as I understand, are equivalent to some kind of assembly functions.

I have not found any example that can guide me. All the HP documentation I have found is about Itanium assembly language, which is a completely different architecture from PA-RISC.

Can someone please point me to some online resources about PA-RISC inline assembly with the HP CC compiler?  Or at least some examples.

Comment: RISC is not an architecture, but a broad term to describe one. Please be more specific about the Chip you are targeting.

Comment: Please STOP SHOUTING. Your Caps Lock key must have stuck while typing the subject line.

Comment: @Axel He's talking about HP's [PA-RISC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PA-RISC) architecture, the predecessor of Itanium.

Answer (score 2):

Your computer speaks Spanish (RISC Assembly).
Somebody wrote instructions in Chinese for a Chinese speaking computer.
You need to translate from Chinese to Spanish.
Not knowing both languages makes it an impossible job, examples notwithstanding.

Suggestion: ask the original programmer to rewrite the code in plain C.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to rewriting the assembly in a different assembler format, you could [use gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/specific.html#hppa-hp-hpux) on your hpux.

Of course, if the assembly was written for a different processor, then you'll have to follow @pmg's advice and ask for a generic C version. (Which is one of the reasons why C became so popular! It worked on multiple architectures once a compiler code generator was written for the target platform! Woot.)